# XML special character escaping in DataWeave

Tags: xml, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a JSON payload consisting of some ascii characters as below.

`Blades with \u000BMahogony/ Natural Wood Fin`

We need to pass the above data as XML to downstream system. I'm trying to use

```
output application/xml escapeGT=true
```

It is working in dataweave playground., where as in anypoint studio it is giving error saying

```
escapeGT is not valid. Valid options are...
```

Need to know which function can be used, so that mule can send the data to downstream system without modifying the data received.

Mule runtime Version: 4.3.0EE

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
var batchSize = p('product.batchSize')
var mapPayload = if (batchSize == '1') [payload] else payload
output application/xml escapeGT=true
---
ItemList: {( mapPayload map {
    Item @(
       ItemID: $.ItemID,
       SyncTS: vars.timeStamp....
```

Comment: Provide the snippet of how your DataWeave script is used in your flow. I'm XML text, not a screenshot. Include the Mule component using it. And the complete error message.

Comment: Also what version of Mule are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The escapeGT writer property is only available from [DataWeave 2.4](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-xml#writer_properties) in Mule 4.4 or later. The documentation for the [previous version](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-formats-xml#properties) shows it is not there. Even if you upgrade it is not clear why this option should work for this case. The option is not for this kind of character. In my opinion it looks to be an undocumented usage that could be removed or fixed in a future release.

The character that you are trying to write is [invalid in XML 1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML). DataWeave throws an error because of trying to write an invalid character.

One option is to just remove the character by replacing it by an empty string, or replace it with a normal white space character. You loose the character but the output will be valid XML.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
import * from dw::core::Strings
---
{ 
    x: replaceAll(payload.description, "\u000B", "") 
}
```

You could instead replace it by a normal space character if you prefer to keep the number of characters: `replaceAll(payload.description, "\u000B", " ")`

If you are using a Mule version older than Mule 4.4 the function `replaceAll()` will not be available. You can instead use the `replace() ... with()` that uses regular expressions:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{ 
    x: payload.description replace /\u000B/ with  " " 
}
```

Another possibility is to encode the character so the XML parser can accept it:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
import * from dw::core::Strings
---
{ 
    x: replaceAll(payload.description, "\u000B", "&#xB;") 
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that it works for DataWeave to write it and if you want to use that as input to another DataWeave script. Having said that it doesn't seem to regenerate the original character so it is not perfect. Third party parsers that actually recognize the character so encoded may still fail.

Setting the output value as CDATA **is not recommended**. It prevents the error from happening but the output is still invalid and will fail as an input for DataWeave.

Comment: Using CDATA does not affect what characters are valid. x0B is invalid in XML 1.0; in XML 1.1 it is valid provided it is written as a character reference, `&#xB;`. But not many XML parsers support 1.1 (I've no idea what parser is being used here.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the insights @MichaelKay. The OP didn't share but in my tests with the next release of Mule it says it is XML 1.1. Interestingly DataWeave allows the character in the output using CDATA, but that output fails as input. Using the character reference you shared works both as inputs and outputs for DataWeave. Both methods fail to validate in an online validator. It seems the result will depend on the parser that will use this output. I will update my answer.

Comment: Setting as CData is not working, I'm still getting the initial error "Invalid white space character (0xb) in text to output (in xml 1.1, could output as a character entity) while writing Xml at ."

Comment: I updated my answer yesito indicate that it is not recommend and suggested alternatives.

Comment: Even replaceAll function is only available from dataweave 2.4 version. So need to check with replace function https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-strings-functions-replaceall

Comment: I added an alternative implementation that uses a function available in earlier Mule versions. For those that have Mule 4.4+ replaceAll() is still preferred.